# Win8 ShareCharm post image to facebook

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm trying to use the Share charm in a Windows Store app to share photos to Facebook.
The image appears when I use the Share charm to send an E-Mail, but not in Facebook.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
private void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
{
   var item = PictureHolder.SelectedItem;
   if (item == null)
   {
       var dialog = new MessageDialog("No image selected.");
       dialog.ShowAsync();
       return;
   }

   var thumbNail = (FileInformation)item;
   var file = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(thumbNail);
   args.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "Win8 ShareCharm FBTest";
   args.Request.Data.Properties.Thumbnail = file;
   args.Request.Data.SetBitmap(file);
}
```

It posts the set title, but not the thumbnail. 
Does Facebook require the data to be set differently?

Note: I am using Windows 8.1

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? 8 or 8.1? The update that allowed you to share to Facebook [appeared to have been added in Windows 8.1](http://www.neowin.net/news/latest-facebook-windows-81-update-adds-share-charm-support-and-more). As such, you'll likely need Windows 8.1.

Comment: I am actually using Windows 8.1. Edited question to specify.

Comment: Have you updated your Facebook app?

Comment: I did. Uninstalled and reinstalled to check that I have the most recent version as well.

Comment: I wonder if that update was share 'out of' as opposed to share 'into'. Does it need to be out of the share charm? Or could you use [something like this](http://facebooksdk.net/).

Comment: I wouldn't know about the first bit. I'll keep researching. As for the Facebook SDK, I'm trying not to use anything outside of the Share Charm, since this is just a research task about Win8 Charms.  Thanks for looking into it though.